# Xlib: Showing the webcam using PIxmap and XDrawPoint is too slow... how can I improve?

Tags: c, xlib

I want to open the webcam and show the video with Xlib.
So, I open the webcam, get the image, and I do something like:

```
for(x = 0; x < webcamX; x++){
    for(y = 0; y < webcamY; y++){
        pixel = GetCameraPixel(x, y);
        XDrawPoint(dpy, pixmap, pixel, x, y);
    }
}
XCopyArea(dpy, pixmal, window, ....);
```

but, calling XDrawPoint is too slow.
I tried also with XImage, but this time XPutPixel and XPutImage are both slows (using Pixmap is faster than XImage)

I think the problem is that doing XDrawPoint 640 * 480 times makes a lot of requests to the X server. The same when doing XPutImage, sending a 640 * 480 image is a lot.. isn't it?

**So, forgetting about the webcam,** imagine I want to do a game, an animation, a video player, or whatever, only with XLib.. is it possible? I am sure that drawing pixel by pixel is not efficient, so how can I do it well? 
All the information I found on the internet is to use Pixmap or XImage, it is better than drawing on the window itself, but it's not enought.

For example, the xscreensavers show a very nice animation in full screen (and I think they only use Xlib), how can they make the animation smoothly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it was my fault I think.
Using XImage is the best way, it is very fast and smooth when drawing pixel by pixel something like the webcam example.
But, I was creating the XImage using the XYPixmap, and it was too slow, I changed to ZPixmap and everything is perfect!

So, the solution I used for the webcam is:

```
image = XCreateImage(dpy, DefaultVisual(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy)), DefaultDepth(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy)), ZPixmap, 0, imagedata, webcamX, webcamY, 32, 0);
/* ....*/
for(x = 0; x < webcamX; x++){
    for(y = 0; y < webcamY; y++){
        pixel = GetCameraPixel(x, y);
        XPutPixel(image, x, y, pixel);
    }
}
XPutImage(dpy, window, gc, image, 0, 0, 0, 0, webcamX, webcamY);
```

- Create an XImage using the ZPixmap format
- Draw in that XImage (using XPutPixel in my case)
- Copy the XImage to the window (using XPutImage)

I think that using XYPixmap was too slow because X needed to do some kind of conversion thus making the process very slow